# Handling messages from different namespaces in Symfony Messenger with RMQ

Tags: symfony, symfony-messenger

I'm building an application with micro services approach. For communication between services I use Symfony Messenger with RMQ transport. Basically everything works fine, but all my services has to be in same namespace. Once I tried to separate them into their own namespaces like `App\Mail`, `App\Auth` and so on messenger was complaining about lack of Event classes because whole namesapce is provided within header of message sent to RMQ. Is there any way I could map events from two different namespaces?

For instance `Auth` app dispatches event `UserRegistered` so message has type of `App\Auth\Event\UserRegistered`. I want to handle that event in my Mail app but messenger can't consume it because my Event and Handler are under `App\Mail` namespace, so it can't find `App\Auth\Event\UserRegistered` class in "Mail" app.

Example error I'm getting:

```sh
In Serializer.php line 85:

  Could not decode message: Could not denormalize object of type App\Event\UserRequestedPasswordReset, no supporting normalizer found.
```

In this exact example I'm sending event UserRequestedPasswordReset from app that is under `App` namespace, and I'm trying to consume it with application under `App\Mail` namespace.

I wasn't able to find anything helpful in documentation or over the internet. I was trying to alias `App\Event\UserRequestedPasswordReset` to `App\Mail\Event\UserRequestedPasswordReset` in container but no luck. I'm guessing that it's something doable with Denormalizers, but also couldn't find anything helpful over internet.

Communication itself is working, messages are sent to RMQ and received in other services. My setup for RMQ is:
I have multiple queues, one for each service. I have fanout exchange with those queues binded. Whenever I'm producing event I'm publishing it to exchange to populate it to all queues, so interested services can handle them.

Example messenger configuration in one of my services. Besides event I'm using messenger to handle CQRS commands and queries, so I'm using three different buses.

```
messenger:
        default_bus: messenger.bus.commands
        buses:
            messenger.bus.commands:
                middleware:
#                    - validation
#                    - doctrine_transaction
            messenger.bus.queries:
                middleware:
#                    - validation
            messenger.bus.events:
                default_middleware: allow_no_handlers
                middleware:
#                    - validation
        transports:
            events:
                dsn: "%env(MESSENGER_AMQP_DSN)%"
                options:
                    exchange:
                        name: ecommerce_events
                        type: fanout
                    queue:
                        name: ecommerce_auth

        routing:
            'App\Event\UserCreated': events
            'App\Event\UserModified': events
            'App\Event\UserChangedPassword': events
            'App\Event\UserRequestedPasswordReset': events
```

I would like to keep my applications in different namespaces and still be able to handle events from other services

Comment: Hi there, I think you have sufficiently described what you're trying to achieve/ensure. However, you said you had an error/problem, but don't provide error messages or the code that produces that error message. the configuration might be helpful at some point but the code and error message are necessary to help you with the specific problem at hand (because that one is missing from your post).

Comment: you're right, sorry. I've edited my original post

Comment: so, the message indicates, that your object was normalized (object->array) but could not be denormalized (array->object). on the docs page for the symfony serializer it says "To use the ObjectNormalizer, the PropertyAccess component must also be installed.". I'm not quite sure, how far your microservices approach goes and if this is relevant though... https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: I think that I have everything it needs, because when I have same namespaces (message type is eg. `App\Events\SomeEvent` and I have my event on same namepsace) there is no problem with consuming the message. Problem occurs when I move one of my services into other namesace and message types don't match (eg message sent has type of `App\Auth\SomeEvent` and receiving service has same event under `App\Mail\SomeEvent`). I docs I can see that when I denormalize "manually" I can provide it with object that I want to normalize to. Problem is I don't know how to do this in messenger.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So after digging into topic I was able to find solution.

I just needed to create custom serializer and then during encoding I was stripping off the namespace and then during decoding I was providing map for type to actual event class. Here is my code

```php
class EventsSerializer extends Serializer
{
    public function encode(Envelope $envelope): array
    {
        $data = parent::encode($envelope);
        $data['headers']['type'] = $this->parseType($data['headers']['type']);

        return $data;
    }

    private function parseType(string $type)
    {
        return end(explode('\\', $type));
    }

    public function decode(array $encodedEnvelope): Envelope
    {
        $translatedType = $this->translateType($encodedEnvelope['headers']['type']);
        $encodedEnvelope['headers']['type'] = $translatedType;

        return parent::decode($encodedEnvelope);
    }

    private function translateType($type)
    {
        $map = [
            'UserCreated' => UserCreated::class,
            'UserRequestedPasswordReset' => UserRequestedPasswordReset::class
        ];

        return $map[$type] ?? $type;
    }
}
```

In messenger configuration:

```yaml
framework:
  messenger:
    serializer:
      default_serializer: AppBundle\Serializer\EventsSerializer
```

Please bare in mind that this is more like proof of concept and it probably can be enhanced, but it's working.

Comment: I made mine a bit more generic, but this is a good base

Comment: For the next person: If you add a `getMessageType` to your message, you can do `return $envelope->getMessage()->getMessageType()` in the `parseType` logic above. Keep in mind to make the counterpart in translateType